# FitNesse-Tests: Unable to parse input. Input ignored

Tags: c#, fitnesse

In Test-Page of a FitNesse Wiki I moved some pages to a sub page.
It would be the equivalent of a structure change like the following:

> - Person Tests
>
>   - Test 1
>   - Test 2
>   - Test 3

to

> - Person Tests
>
>   - Test 1
>   - Group 1
>
>     - Test 2
>     - Test 3

All the test pages still pass when executed individually. But when I test either the one that represents Person Tests or Group 1 in my example, I get the following error:

> Test System: fit:dotnet2\Runner.exe
>  Unable to parse input. Input
>   ignored.

The FitNesse Tests System tests a REST API written in C#.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to mark the pages "Person Tests" and "Group 1" as Suite. That fixed the problem.